# How to convert binary into a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, binary

I have been trying to convert my binary into a string in python. Haven't really figured out any solution at all. Anyone got an idea? Below is my code for how I convert the said strings into binary. I don't know if that is useful?

```
def binary_converter(string):
   for character in string:
        print(bin(ord(character))[2:].zfill(8))

binary_converter("Hello World!")
```

Comment: use `b'my binary data'.decode()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert bytes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of

```
bin(ord(character))[2:].zfill(8)
```

is

```
chr(int(binary_str, 2))
```

where `binary_str` is, for example, `01001000` for the letter `H`.

What remains is just wrapping this in a loop.  I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to convert it to string is `str.decode()`. For example, `b"binary code".decode()` will return the string.